# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 not available to boot

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

I have tried a live CD for both 12.10 and 13.04 and done the install alongside Windows 7 option.  It gets to the point it asks me where to install and the ONLY option in the drop down is my WD Passport external drive.    I have not created a partition on my internal drive.   Either way, Ubuntu completes the install, and reboots.   Immediately Windows 7 loads, no option to boot to Ubuntu to try it out.
If I go into the boot options by using F8, I can change boot device and my external drive shows twice.    If I select the one, I get a GRUB prompt that says it can not boot.   If I select the other (SES) then it starts into Windows 7 right away (Windows is not installed on that drive, although there is a partition there for backup files).
Is Ubuntu unable to boot from an external device?   Would seem odd since a flash drive or CD both work.   Or do I need to create a partition on my internal main drive to allow Ubuntu to dual boot?

Comment: How many bootable devices show up in your BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a /etc/fstab problem.

You have to reboot with the live CD, mount the external disk (where you installed Ubuntu), and check the /etc/fstab file that resides on that external disk.

You have to edit /etc/fstab to make  sure that when you boot from the external disk,  the root of your filesystem is mounted on that bootable disk (probably /dev/sdb1).

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab

Then you have probably another problem.
GRUB sets root on (hd0,0), the first disk, first partition. (but that is the sda-disk, first partition).

So GRUB must set root on the second disk,first partition, that is (hd1,0)
Still running the live CD, you have to run grub-installer.

See: http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/677

Afterwards, check your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.